# File download box with Angular2 and Spring MVC

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

We have an application that supports export to excel on search results. 
The search results are paged and lazily loaded. However on export the users want all the pages to be exported.

The export is handled on the server where we get all the data and create an xlsx file which shows up as a file download. The export takes a little while (about a minute) at which point I have 2 options:

1. Show a glass panel to the user which prevents him from doing anything else
2. Do not show a glass panel, and let the user continue to work on the application while the download is in progress

I was trying to implement #2. The download works, however there is no visual indication given to the user that download is in progress. I would like to show the browser download file dialog that appears at the bottom of the browser window while the download is in progress but cannot get it to show.

I am using Filesaver.js:

```
FileSaver.saveAs(response, 'SheetName.xlsx')
```

Relevant http headers being passed from the server:

```
content-disposition:attachment; filename="SheetName.xlsx"
content-language:en-US
expires:0
pragma:private
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

I am using Spring MVC with Apache POI at the server side to create the excel. 
Not sure on how to proceed. Any suggestions?